# Chat Server with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm learning Python Twisted and this is my example about chat server from my book:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class ChatProtocol(LineReceiver):
  def __init__(self, factory):
    self.factory = factory
    self.name = None
    self.state = "REGISTER"

  def connectionMade(self):
    self.sendLine("What's your name?")

  def connectionLost(self, reason):
    if self.name in self.factory.users:
        del self.factory.users[self.name]
        self.broadcastMessage("%s has left the channel !" %(self.name))

  def LineReceived(self, line):
    if self.state == "REGISTER" :
        self.handle_REGISTER(line)
    else:
        self.handle_CHAT(line)

  def handle_REGISTER(self, name):
    if name in self.factory.users:
        self.sendLine("Name taken, choose another!")
        return
    self.sendLine("Welcome, %s !" %(name))
    self.broadcastMessage("%s has joined channel!" %(name))
    self.name = name
    self.factory.users[name]= self
    self.state = "CHAT"

  def handle_CHAT(self, message):
    message = " <%s>  %s" %(self.name, message)
    self.broadcastMessage(message)

  def broadcastMessage(self, message):
    for name, protocol in self.factory.users.iteritems():
        if protocol != self:
            protocol.sendLine(message)

class ChatFactory(Factory):
  def __init__(self):
    self.users = {}

  def buildProtocol(self, addr):
    return ChatProtocol(self)

reactor.listenTCP(7100, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

And I connect by: telnet localhost 7100.
It worked and asked me: what's your name?, but when I type my name, the sever raise this error:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 103, in 
callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 86, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
   return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 149, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 208, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 214, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\basic.py", line 625, in lineReceived
    raise NotImplementedError
exceptions.NotImplementedError:
```

I'm very new to this so I really do not understand much.

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive.

You have:

```
  def LineReceived(self, line):
      ...
```

But instead you should have:

```
  def lineReceived(self, line):
      ...
```

Since the method you've defined doesn't have the right name, the *inherited* method is used.  That method has an implementation that raises the exception you're seeing.

Also, switch to using four space indents.  It will improve readability and it's essentially the standard in Python.